# Override Referential equality check for Material-UI Select Dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, dropdown

I am trying to build a dropdown using `Select` with `MenuItem` tag from Material-UI.
As Per Material-UI Documentation `value` attribute in Select tag is as follows

[image]

I want to know if we can override the reference equality check of this value item

Problem Faced:
Trying to store a object type of value with use of redux. Hence it does the reference equality check properly for the first time but on refresh redux stringify and parse the object again which does a deep copy of the object hence creating a new object which fails the reference equality check

My Code

```html
<Select fullWidth variant="outlined" label={"business"}
        value={this.props.tripPlanning.tripBusinessLine}
        name={Constants.TRIP_PLANNING_FIELD_BUSINESS_LINE}
        onChange={this.handleTripBusinessLineDropdown}>

        {this.props.maps.segments.map((segment) => {
         console.log('NO REFRESH', segment === this.props.tripPlanning.tripBusinessLine)
         console.log('PAGE REFRESH CASE', segment === JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.tripPlanning.tripBusinessLine)))
         return (<MenuItem value={segment}>{segment.segmentName}</MenuItem>)
        })}
</Select>
```

My on page refresh console is always false.

```
segment structure 
{
  segmentId: 144
  segmentName: "Team Operations"
  subSegments: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}
```